# How to compare two arraylist containing objects with shared properties?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How to compare two arraylist containing objects with shared properties?

For example, I have a pojo class Abc:

```
Class Abc {
String dataString ;
int rowNum;
......
}

Abc list1 contains - 2000 records & more sometimes
Abc list2 contains - 60 records & more sometimes
```

I want to compare list1 dataString to list2 datastring and return rownum
if list1.dataString Notequals list2.dataString

I need rowNumber from List1 if data string DOESN'T matches. List2 Rownum can be ignored.

Comment: So, you want the `rowNums` of all the objects in both list1 and list2 that share the same `dataString`?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Yes correct, I need rowNumbers from list1 if its matching in list2. I dont care for List2 row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In high-level terms, your code should:

- iterate over list1
- for each element check whether its data string appears somewhere in list2
- if so, include the row number of the list1 element in the result

To make the code fast, in the second step the set of list2 data strings can be precomputed. Still in high-level terms, the code is:

```
List<int> filtered(List<Abc> list1, List<Abc> list2) {
    var dataStrings = setOf(list2.map(x -> x.dataString));

    var abcs = list1.filter(x -> dataStrings.contains(x.dataString));

    return abcs.map(x -> x.rowNum);
}
```

In standard Java, the code looks more bloated, of course:

```
List<int> filtered(List<Abc> list1, List<Abc> list2) {
    Set<String> dataStrings = list2.stream()
        .map(x -> x.dataString))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return list1.stream()
        .filter(x -> dataStrings.contains(x.dataString))
        .map(x -> x.rowNum)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: The above solution works for my original request. Small correction on my original question.I want to return the rowNum which doesnot match the dataString b/w list1 and list2. List2 rown num can be ignored.

Comment: I am new to Streams concept. I am using java 8

Comment: I tried return list1.stream().filter(x -> !dataStrings.contains(x.getDataString())).map(x -> x.getRowNum()).collect(Collectors.toList()); and it worked

Comment: I want to add +1 to every rowNum from returned list. How can I do that in streams.

Comment: To learn more about Java streams, read the official documentation by searching for "Java streams site:oracle.com", and additional introductions. Anything written by Baeldung is also trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If in this case, you have two different lists and wants to have comparison, one of the simple way to do that can be two foreach loops with equality condition and then having the value:

```
for(Abc list1Obj : list1)
{
      for(Abc list2Obj : list2)
      {
          if(list1.dataString.Equals(list2.dataString))
          {
              int value = Integer.parseInt(list1.rowNumber);
          }
      }
}
```

In this case, it would for each item in list1 with each item in list2.

Comment: This is a Java question, not C#. :)

Comment: My bad, for convert i remember i need to change but i think equals is correct in this context. Isnt it?

Comment: In Java, method names start with a lowercase letter. It should be `equals`.